# What should the name of our chat room be?

Tags: discussion, chat

Did you know we have a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6619/politics)? It feels a bit deserted and one fun way of drawing a bit of attention to it would be to change the default - and dull - name to something awesome!

Several other sites have cool names for their main chat rooms, some examples are:

- [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), Programmer's main room
- [The Water Cooler](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler), The Workplace's main room
- [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/179/the-heap), DBA's main room
- [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/118/root-access), Super User's main room
- [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35/the-bridge), Gaming's main room
- [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/mos-eisley), SciFi's main room

Unfortunately, [The Assembly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly) is already taken.

This is a straight up poll, and the Q&A platform doesn't cope particularly well with polls, so let's limit this to a week. Top voted answer after a week wins, at which point we'll close the question.

**update #1**

The week's over, and... it's a tie! Let's extend the poll for three more days, but please only vote for either [Agora](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/151/101) or [The Soapbox](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/153/101). If it's still a tie after three days, I'll flip a coin ;)

**update #2**

We have a winner, Agora!

Comment: Well the week was up yesterday and we're left with a tie between The Soapbox and Agora. I propose we extend the time limit by 3 days to see if we can get a decision between the two.

Comment: @GrahamWager That's fine by me, still we should close this, there's no need for further answers, voting can go on even if it's closed.

Comment: My only concern with closing is it may detract attention from it. Perhaps a simple update of the question stating that all but these two have been eliminated and no new answers will be considered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Agora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agora)

Comment: Awesome! And the first picture in the Wikipedia article is from my home town!

Comment: I do like the idea of this one, but some might complain the reference isn't *necessarily* obvious to politics fanatics. (Full disclosure: That hasn't kept me from using a particular room name before...)

Comment: I came here to suggest this! :D

Comment: All of the other suggestions are too American- or British-centered. Why not [Hôtel Lambert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B4tel_Lambert)? "Agora" is at least only single-civilization-centered and not single-culture-centered.

Answer (score 4):

The [Soapbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soapbox)

Answer (score 4):

### The House of Commons

I do like this one for a General chat, because of the historical implication that it's filled with common folk as opposed to the privileged. Even though that really isn't true.

Answer (score 3):

[The Smoke-Filled Back Room](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_filled_room), of course.

Comment: Like the idea, maybe more appropriate for a moderators room though ;)

Comment: Naw. Moderator chat room should be "Town Hall".

Comment: I was thinking "The Watergate" for the mod room ...

Comment: Tammany hall, rather

Answer (score 3):

**The Tavern**

Advantage: Everybody talks politics in taverns, clear back to when Lugal-Zage-Si and his cousin Is-Agez-Lagul put their heads together over a glass of   and plotted to overthrow King Ur-Zababa.

Disadvantage: Everybody talks politics in taverns after imbibing alcoholic beverages.

Comment: Honestly when people start talking politics in the bar I usually get up and leave...

Comment: @Chad Drunk politics are the best politics!

Comment: @YannisRizos - Nothing says lively debate like a good drunken bar brawl...

Answer (score 3):

Upon thinking more, how about ..

#### The Filibuster

Not only is it on topic, I think it's a perfect backdrop for a room full of very chatty people :)

Comment: Too US-specific IMO.

Comment: It's not *quite* that narrow.

Answer (score 1):

[Speakers' Corner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speakers%27_Corner)

> A Speakers' Corner is an area where open-air public speaking, debate and discussion are allowed.

(Last one, I promise.)

Answer (score 0):

### Debate Floor

That is, if debates will be happening there.

Answer (score 0):

### Parliament

A little more general than my other idea.

Answer (score 0):

### Hotel de Bilderberg

[* just because](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilderberg_Hotel)

<sub>Hmm, I might have a slight obsession with [hotel related](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel) room names.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

### Town Square

Evokes the revolutionary sharing their ideas to the town citizens as they pass by.

Answer (score -2):

Alright, to avoid localization, consternation and set a productive tone - how about:

#### The Voting Booth

That, at least to me, seems appropriate for many countries and sets a positive, topical tone.

Answer (score -2):

**Forum Romanum or Forum Magnum**

> The Roman Forum (Latin: Forum Romanum, Italian: Foro Romano) is a rectangular forum (plaza) surrounded by the ruins of several important ancient government buildings at the center of the city of Rome. Citizens of the ancient city referred to this space, originally a marketplace, as the Forum Magnum, or simply the Forum.
>
> It was for centuries the center of Roman public life: the site of triumphal processions and elections, venue for public speeches, criminal trials, and gladiatorial matches, and nucleus of commercial affairs. Here statues and monuments commemorated the city's great men. The teeming heart of ancient Rome, it has been called the most celebrated meeting place in the world, and in all history. Located in the small valley between the Palatine and Capitoline Hills, the Forum today is a sprawling ruin of architectural fragments and intermittent archeological excavations attracting numerous sightseers.

Answer (score -3):

Pundit room?

Answer (score -3):

### Non-Binding Referendum

The name just sounds fun